# How to initialize a Java Date object in Spring xml configuration file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

Consider this simple example -

```
public class Person
 {
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    // getters and setters here...
 }
```

In order to initialize Person as a Spring bean, I can write the following.

```
<bean id = "Michael" class = "com.sampleDomainName.Person">
<property name = "name" value = "Michael" />
</bean>
```

But in the above bean definition, how can I set the dateOfBirth?

For eg. I want to set the dateOfBirth as

```
1998-05-07
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the answers mentioned here is useful, but it needs additional information. The constructor arguments for the CustomDateEditor need to be supplied.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
  <property name="customEditors">
    <map>
      <entry key="java.util.Date"> <ref local = "customDateEditor" /> 
      </entry> 
    </map>
  </property> 
</bean>

<bean id = "customDateEditor" class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
          <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
       </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg value="true" /> 
</bean>
```

Now we can do

```
<property name="dateOfBirth" value="1998-05-07" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Treat it like any other POJO (which is is)

```
<property name="dateOfBirth">
  <bean class="java.util.Date" />
</property>
```

If you need to use an explicit value (such as 1975-04-10), then simply call one of the other constructors (although those which take year-month-day are deprecated). You could also use an explicit `java.beans.PropertyEditor` which [Spring rolls with already](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) (see section **6.4.2**; note that you can write your own editors and register them for your own types). You need to register the *CustomEditorConfigurer* in your config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
  <property name="customEditors">
    <map>
      <entry key="java.util.Date" 
             value="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor"/>
    </map>
  </property> 
</bean>
```

Then your data looks like:

```
<property name="dateOfBirth" value="1975-04-10" />
```

I might add that `Date` is *not an appropriate data type* to store a date-of-birth because `Date` is really an *instant-in-time*. You might like to look at **Joda** and use the `LocalDate` class.

Comment: He probably wants to initialize it to specific date not current time.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring inject Date into bean property – CustomDateEditor](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/)

This paper give two suggestions:

1. Factory bean
2. CustomDateEditor

I suggest the "Factory Bean" because the CustomDateEditor is not supported in Spring 4.0+ and the Factory Bean is easy enough to use.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
        <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customer" class="com.mkyong.common.Customer">
        <property name="date">
            <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
                <constructor-arg value="2010-01-31" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you include some basics of what the link covers? Otherwise if this link is unreachable in the future, this answer will not communicate anything anymore.

Comment: @DanLowe Hi，I have add a example from the link I suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CustomDateEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html).  It's been in Spring since the early days.