# How to configure customEditors property of CustomEditorConfigurer in Spring 4.0.6

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am migrating from Spring 3.2.4 to Spring 4.0.6 and I couldnt configure CustomEditorConfigurer in the newer version

Below was the configuration for Spring 3.2.4 in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.util.Date">
                <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
                    <constructor-arg index="0">
                        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                            <constructor-arg value="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I tried to use the same configuration in Spring 4.0.6 then am getting below error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/core/admin-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[java.util.Date]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[java.util.Date]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[java.util.Date]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:263)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedMap(TypeConverterDelegate.java:623)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
    ... 34 more
```

I've compared the `CustomEditorConfigurer` class in Spring 3.2.4 and Spring 4.0.6 and noticed there is a change in `customEditors` type. In Spring 4.0.6 `customEditors` type is `Map<Class<?>, Class<? extends PropertyEditor>> customEditors;` compared to Spring 3.2.4 `Map<String, ?> customEditors;`

Can someone help me configuring it for Spring 4.0.6

Comment: I suggest you use Formatter<T> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html, it is more flexible and useful

Comment: You may find the answer here - same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706869/string-to-date-conversion-in-spring-4-0