# SoapVersion conversion with Spring Framework 4

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am moving my code from `Spring` 3 to 4. I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersionPropertyEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersion]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersionPropertyEditor] at ...
```

I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706869/string-to-date-conversion-in-spring-4-0) to write the following but it is not solve my issue.

In my `servlet.xml` file I added:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
       <list>
          <bean class="com.company.CustomEditor"/>
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I added this class in my project:

```
public class CustomEditor implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

 @Override
 public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
     registry.registerCustomEditor(SoapVersion.class, new SoapPropertyEditor());
 }
}
```

How do you fix the `soapVersion` issue in Spring 4? 
I am new to spring.
Thank you

Comment: The issue might be a compatibility issue. My version of apache cxf is 2.0 and I am using Spring framework 4

Answer (score 0):

in the **spring congfiuration** file you need to change the xsd version to resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you for the comment. All my  spring configuration xml have the correct version -4.3.xml