# Why cant we inject DATE Direct from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Bean for Date,and I inject a Date from spring in following manner in Spring configuration xml.

```
<bean id="customer" class="com.my.common.Customer">
        <property name="date" value="2014-11-12" />
    </bean>
```

After Running I get following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
    Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to 
    required type [java.util.Date] for property 'date'; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to
    required type [java.util.Date] for property 'date': 
    no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Why is it so? Can any one explain why is it not working.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198297/how-to-initialize-a-java-date-object-in-spring-xml-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

Even if `Customer#date` is a `java.util.Date`, how could Spring know how to parse the `2014-11-12` input string? Sure `yyyy-MM-dd` is a quite common date pattern, but there is no *standard default date pattern* though.

One solution is to use a factory bean:

```xml
<bean id="dateFormatter" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</bean>

<bean id="customer" class="com.veke.common.Customer">
    <property name="date">
        <bean factory-bean="dateFormatter" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="2014-11-12" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Custom InitBinder in your controller class

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder, Locale locale,HttpServletRequest request) {
        //set your requred date format
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        //spring will bind every Date String to java.util.Date
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,true));
}
```